# @Output from Child component doesn't trigger EventEmitter in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I would like the child component to send some data to the parent component. The child part is executed as expected, but the parent code doesn't react, and there are no errors. So if have any idea ...

Child HTML

```
<button  (click)="sendDataToParent()">  CLICK ME !  </button>
```

Child TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../Hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-detail.component.css']
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() hero : Hero;   
  @Output() sendDataHeroEvent: EventEmitter<Hero> = new EventEmitter<Hero>();

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }

  sendDataToParent(event: any){
    let hero2: Hero; hero2 = new Hero();  hero2.id = 12; hero2.name = "Narco";
    this.sendDataHeroEvent.emit(hero2);
    console.log("OK, child emits data to parent");
  }
}
```

Parent HTMl

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes"
    (sendDataHeroEvent)="sendDataHeroEventHandler($event)">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" 
        (click)="onSelect(hero)"
        [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
        class="drag-box" 
        cdkDragLockAxis="y"
        cdkDrag> 
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>
```

Parent TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
...
sendDataHeroEventHandler(event){
    console.log("OK, parent handler is called");
}
```

In the console log of chrome, i get 
"OK, child emits data to parent"
but i do not get
"OK, parent handler is called"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not binding the output property correctly to your child component. In fact there is no output property binding. Modify the below code

```
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>
```

to

```
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero" (sendDataHeroEvent)="sendDataHeroEventHandler($event)"></app-hero-detail>
```

and remove the binding from here:

```
<ul class="heroes"
    **(sendDataHeroEvent)="sendDataHeroEventHandler($event)"**> // Take this out
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" 
        (click)="onSelect(hero)"
        [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
        class="drag-box" 
        cdkDragLockAxis="y"
        cdkDrag> 
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks.  And for getting the Hero send by the child, i used the following function on the TS of parent side : sendDataHeroEventHandler($event: Hero){    console.log("parent " + $event.name);  }

Answer (score 2):

Add the event handler in child component selector tag.

```
<app-hero-detail 
  [hero]="selectedHero"
  (sendDataHeroEvent)="sendDataHeroEventHandler($event)">
</app-hero-detail>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the template of your parent to

```
<ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" 
        (click)="onSelect(hero)"
        [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
        class="drag-box" 
        cdkDragLockAxis="y"
        cdkDrag> 
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero" (sendDataHeroEvent)="sendDataHeroEventHandler($event)"></app-hero-detail>
```